# Passing props using userouter on Next.js

Tags: react-hooks, next.js

I've been following this guide on how to render props from my sidebar to my title header based on this links:

[Dynamic Navigation in Next.js](https://freecodecamp.org/news/dynamic-navigation-in-nextjs/)

But it doesnt show up on my title component

Here is my current settings. Basically I wanted to change the title on my header based on the sub-url that were defined in my arrays

From sidebar.tsx

```
import { navItems } from "../../static/NavItems";
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [activeIcon, setActiveIcon] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <LogoContainer>
        <Logo>
          <Image src={logo} alt="Logo" width={200} />
        </Logo>
      </LogoContainer>
      <NavItemsContainer>
        {navItems.map((nav, i) => (
          <NavItem key={i} onClick={() => setActiveIcon(nav.title)}>
            <NavIcon style={{ color: nav.title === activeIcon && "#3773f5" }}>
              {nav.icon}
            </NavIcon>
            <NavTitle>
              <Link as={nav.as} href={nav.path}>
                {nav.title}
              </Link>
            </NavTitle>
          </NavItem>
        ))}
      </NavItemsContainer>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

from title component

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";


const Title = ({ title }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return <div>{{router.pathname === "/" ? title : ""}</div>;
};
```

So in my header, I've just import the component and pass it as a props like this

```
import { Title } from '../title.tsx';

const Header = ({ title }) => {

return (
<Title title={title} />
)
```

is there anything that I missed here?

Comment: Where is the `Header` component being used? Also, if you add `console.log(router.pathname)` inside your `Title` component what's the output?

Comment: Header and Sidebar is part of the Layout page.Tried to console.log but doesnt return anything